# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS crashing on Acer Aspire 5750G

Tags: bios, acer-aspire, ubuntu-18.04, acpi, nouveau

I have tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Acer Aspire 5750G laptop, several times. Until now I have successfully installed the OS two times, only to have it crash after a period of approximately two weeks. What happens when it crashes is either one of the following:

- I get to the Ubuntu login screen, but after entering my password the
  screen simply remains dark. If I choose Weyland instead, the screen
  goes dark for a few seconds until it returns to the login screen.
- When the laptop is booting, I get several error messages.
  Unfortunately I dont have a screenshot of the messages.

Now when I try to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from USB, I get the following messages:

[image]

So it won't even let me reinstall Ubuntu again. It seems I was just lucky the two other times where I succeeded installing Ubuntu. One time it seemed that simply changing the USB port, allowed me to install the OS.

Reading about similar problems, I suspect it has something to do with the dedicated Nvidia GPU. Last time Ubuntu worked for me on the laptop, I made sure that I was using the integrated graphics.

Specifications:

- Intel (R) Core (TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
- Nvidia Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M]
- System BIOS version: v1.07
- VGA BIOS version: Intel v2098
- VGA BIOS version (PEG): nVidia N12P-GS VER70.08.3C.00.19

Comment: Have you installed the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Yes, I tried to install it using this guide: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04. I used the proprietary, tested.

Comment: And have you disabled Secure Boot in UEFI settings? The problem is it prevents Nvidia drivers from loading even if correctly and successfully installed. Users need to either disable Secure Boot (easy) or keep it and then use a tool to sign the Nvidia drivers (expert level).

Comment: In BIOS there's no option to disable Secure Boot. I assume the laptop doesn't support it. I even tried to update the BIOS to see if that helped, but it still didn't give me the option to disable. So the next step is to sign the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Does it have something related to CSM/Legacy? If so first disable that option to assure the installer is booting in UEFI mode (with Legacy enabled, Secure Boot makes no sense so perhapds that's the reason why in a reasonably modern and definitely UEFI machine such option isn't available -or- you aren't seeing it).

Comment: I used Rufus to create a bootable USB with Ubuntu, if that's what you mean. I chose MBR (BIOS or UEFI). I followed a guide to disable Secure Boot on a Acer PC, but under the Boot tab, the Secure Boot option is not listed.

Comment: If it boots then it confirms you're booting in Lagacy/CSM mode (it won't boot in UEFI mode with those Rufus settings). Just check the firmware (UEFI) settings properly as I suggested before and makes sure "UEFI only" + Secure Boot disabled... Then make the installation USB properly with the opposite settings of those you chose. This will assure you're booting (and installing) in the correct mode.

Comment: I just created an installation media for Ubuntu with GPT and UEFI (not CSM). I get the following message: `ERROR: LEGACY BOOT OF UEFI MEDIA. This drive can only boot in UEFI mode. It can not boot in BIOS/Legacy mode.`

Comment: Exactly! :) That's why I told you a few times already to disable CSM/Legacy or anything similar in the firmware in in order to assure it is actually booting in UEFI mode.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer @GabrielaGarcia. I have tried several times and different methods to disable CSM/Legacy or something similar to boot into UEFI mode, but I can't get it to work. Please see this album: https://imgur.com/a/q9eYeRM